# Sum of all values in a class tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want the Grand Total calculation now.. I want the sum of all the values in the Amount field... I tried tis code but its not working...

```
$(".amt").each(function(){
    total=total+(parseInt($(this).val()))
});
```

[image]

Comment: and what have you tried??

Comment: provide some HTML or a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: For ur kind information parseFloat() and parseInt() are not working.. We should use the Number()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="amt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="amt" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
```

The JS would be:

```
$('table').focusout(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.amt').each(function(){
        if (this.value != "") {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $('#total').html("Grand total: " + sum);
});
```

<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RkM2/)</kbd>

Comment: Working :)... Thanks :)... But one small doubt... parseFloat() is not working for me, i dnt know y.. I used Number()...

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding these dynamically, you will need to have something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.count', function()
{
    var total = 0;
    $(".amt").each(function()
    {
        total=total+(parseInt($(this).val()))
    });

    alert(total);
});
```